# Recursively defined probability, finding expected value $\Bbb E[X]$.

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

Consider a pmf where $P(X=i)$ is defined for $i = 0, 1, 2$ and for some constant $c$, $$cP(X=i-1)=P(X=i)$$ for $i = 1, 2$. What is the expected value $\Bbb E[X]$ of this pmf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute $i=1,2$ in the given relation you get the system 
\begin{cases}cP(X=1-1)=P(X=1)\\cP(X=2-1)=P(X=2)\\P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=1\end{cases} where the last equation stands because all probabilities must sum up to $1$. This system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns gives $$\begin{cases}P(X=1)=cP(X=0)\\P(X=2)=c^2P(X=0)\\P(X=0)(1+c+c^2)=1\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}P(X=1)=\frac{c}{1+c+c^2}\\P(X=2)=\frac{c^2}{1+c+c^2}\\P(X=0)=\frac{1}{1+c+c^2}\end{cases}$$ Hence $$E[X]=0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)=\frac{c+2c^2}{1+c+c^2}$$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I got, but my teacher claimed that it was possible to solve for c and would only give partial credit to answers in terms of c, is this true?

Comment: No, I do not think that I can solve for $c$. Is that all you are given? Ok, $c$ must be positive etc. which restricts its possible values but it could be anything. For example this exercise works for $c=2$ for $c=3$ etc without a problem. Perhaps I am missing something, but I do not think so.

Comment: Exactly what I proved when answering, nothing is missing, he has been wrong before so hopefully he is again. I was just curious to see if I was missing something, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I think that he is wrong, but wait perhaps someone else here has another insight.

Comment: If you guys are missing something, then so am I.

Comment: he was in fact wrong

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. So, questioning everything / everyone is the way to go...